# ¿Cómo crear una variable global? C#

Tags: c#, variables

Quiero mostrar el usuario, puesto y sucursal del usuario que ha iniciado sesión, antes en .net lo declaraba en un módulo y ahí declaraba como public pero ahora en c# me he perdido un poco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando winform o consola (o similares) es una tema y si estas con web con ASP.NET sea webforms o mvc es otro tema esto de variables globales.

Como no aclaras, suponemos que es para winform.
Si bien lo puedes utilizar como variable global a una clase estática ([Static en C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)) con un una propiedad estática. O sea [utilizar Clases estáticas con método estáticos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Estas clases con propiedades estáticas te puede ser útil, tienes que tener en cuenta solamente la concurrencia, para eso puedes decorar con el atributo [ThreadStatic](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Algo así

```
public static class UsuarioActual{
     [ThreadStatic]
     private static int _puestoId;

     [ThreadStatic]
     private static string _puestoDescripcion;

     public static string PuestoDescripcion {
        get {
              return _puestoDescripcion;
        }
     }

    public static void Init(int puestoId, string puestoDescripcion){
        _puestoId = puestoId;
        _puestoDescripcion = puestoDescripcion;
     }

}
```

O sea, básicamente seria implementar el patrón Singleton en la clase UsuarioActual. Dale una mirada este patrón de diseño. Pero en el patrón tienes otra forma de implementarlo casi sin static.

**RECOMENDACIÓN:** Ya que tienes winform (espero que sea así) y estos datos de usuario seria bueno que lo implementes con [AppSettings de usuario y/o aplicacion](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/using-application-settings-and-user-settings). Es decir puedes setear estos valores que necesitas alli e incluso te servira para "recordar el usuario", asi cuando abra la aplicacion puedes colocar los datos para el ingreso (o incluso recordar el login por x horas, etc) pero para trabajar en winform es muy util a mi parecer
Aqui tienes un ejemplo de como escribir

- [How To: Write User Settings at Run Time with C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-write-user-settings-at-run-time-with-csharp)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Answer (score 0):

C# es un Lenguaje de programación orientado a objetos y no soporta las variables globales directamente. La solución seria agregar clases estáticas que contengan variables "globales". Usar Variables globales contradice un poco el concepto de POO pero puede ser útil en algunas circunstancias.
un ejemplo:

```
class Bread
{
    public int counter;
}

static class Butter
{
    public static int counter;
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // instance of class "Butter" required
        Bread a = new Bread();
        a.counter = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Bread: " + a.counter);

        // no instance required!
        Butter.counter = 5;
        Console.WriteLine("Butter: " + Butter.counter);
    }
}
```

[Mi Fuente](https://www.arclab.com/en/kb/csharp/global-variables-fields-functions-static-class.html)